# Missing scrollbars even with overflow:scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm updating an existing intranet site that had previously been auto-generated by some software years ago.  Needless to say the code was an absolute disaster.  The client didn't want to change the look at all, but wanted the code to be easier to update.  So I proceeded to update the code to include CSS for formatting and getting rid of all the old font tags etc.  When I was done, in the middle of the page, there is a div that contains a months worth or motivational sayings that the user can scroll through.  When I look at it on my browsers (Firefox 25, IE 10), everything looks perfect.  I upload to their servers and move on.  I get a call from the client saying that there are no scroll bars on this middle section. I check my version and everything looks good.  I double check to make sure they have the right version loaded on their servers.  Everything is good.  I decide to take a look on my phone: no scroll bars.  I'm running Firefox 28 on my phone, but neither it nor the default browser shows scroll bars.  Originally, I had set `overflow-y:scroll;` to maintain alignment.  I read that certain browsers have trouble with the `overflow-y` property, so I changed it to `overflow:scroll;` that didn't work either.

To make sure that I didn't have some overriding style somewhere (the code is still stuffed with inline CSS - the client didn't want to add a new file: UGH!), so I made a test html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <body style='background-color: red;'>
   <div style='background-color: blue; width:500px; height:500px; overflow:scroll;'>
     Hello World!
   </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Still no scroll bars on my phone (they show up fine on my PC browsers).

Are there some overriding browser settings or other issues that prevents scroll bars from displaying for divs?  Am I missing something else?

Edit: My Phone is a Samsung Galaxy S III.  However, my client is using a PC and he has no scroll bars either (I'm not sure what versions of the browsers he is using).  Also, on the phone, I can scroll the div via touch, but there are no scroll bars, even in desktop mode.

Additional Edit: This site is not intended for mobile use, so I'm not concerned if the scroll bars don't show up on my phone, I only used my phone to test on another browser.

Comment: What is "your phone"? iPhones for example never show scrollbars unless you scroll.

Comment: On Firefox 25 for Android, an element which has scrollbars on a PC didn't have them in Firefox, although I couldn't scroll. In some ancient webkit browser for Android, you can't scroll at all, and I had to add touch events on another website for it to work.

Comment: Samsung GS3.  Edited OP to add that info.